# Reverse vlookup and concatenate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have table data as shown below. Column A is unique but column B is not.
I want B18 to show all the column A values that maps to APPLE  ie (B18 should be "A,C,E,G")
Is this possible ?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Which version of excel do you have?

Comment: The version is O365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `TEXTJOIN()`, either with Excel O365 or Excel 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A1:A8,B1:B8=A18))
```

Or a CSE variant in 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(B1:B8=A18,A1:A8,""))
```